# GDAL undefined reference Qt С++

Tags: c++, qt

Скачал библиотеку GDAL с помощью OSGeo4W, пробывал через MinGW несколько раз, не получалось.. Подключил в .pro файл библиотеку, не знаю правильно ли, но вроде работает:

```
INCLUDEPATH +=  "C:\OSGeo4W64\include"
LIBS += C:\OSGeo4W64\lib\gdal_i.lib
```

Затем в main, пытаюсь выполнить одну функцию и получаю ошибку "undefined reference".

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "gdal.h"
#include "gdal_priv.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
     GDALAllRegister();

     return a.exec();
 }
```

Что делать подскажите?